# How do I use URIs to load file in combiTable1Ds in Openmodelica?

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

In OpenModelica 1.14.0, I want to load some data from a file into a combiTable1Ds. I want to use a Modelica URI to specify the path in a portable fashion (i.e. not with a full absolute path).

However I specify the `fileName` argument, though, I always get an error that the file cannot be found.

Minimal example:

I have the following package layout:

```
├── TestURI2
│   ├── loadURI2.mo
│   ├── package.mo
│   ├── package.order
│   └── somefile.txt
```

and in the file `loadURI2.mo`

```
within TestURI2;

model loadURI2
  Integer x;
  String filepath = Modelica.Utilities.Files.loadResource("modelica://TestURI2/somefile.txt");
  Modelica.Blocks.Tables.CombiTable1Ds combiTable1Ds(fileName = "modelica://TestURI2/somefile.txt", tableName = "bla", tableOnFile = true)  annotation(Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-60, 68}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
equation
combiTable1Ds.u = time;
x  = Modelica.Utilities.Strings.length(filepath);
end loadURI2;
```

If I comment out the lines related to `combiTable1Ds`, the model compiles and x shows the correct length of the path to the file, indicating that `loadResource` correctly identifies the path from the URI `modelica://TestURI2/somefile.txt`.

If I leave `combiTable1Ds` active, I get

```
/tmp/OpenModelica_bilderbuchi/OMEdit/TestURI2.loadURI2/TestURI2.loadURI2 -port=34607 -logFormat=xmltcp -override=startTime=0,stopTime=1,stepSize=0.002,tolerance=1e-6,solver=dassl,outputFormat=mat,variableFilter=.* -r=/tmp/OpenModelica_bilderbuchi/OMEdit/TestURI2.loadURI2/TestURI2.loadURI2_res.mat -w -lv=LOG_STATS -inputPath=/tmp/OpenModelica_bilderbuchi/OMEdit/TestURI2.loadURI2 -outputPath=/tmp/OpenModelica_bilderbuchi/OMEdit/TestURI2.loadURI2
... loading "bla" from "modelica://TestURI2/somefile.txt"

Not possible to open file "modelica://TestURI2/somefile.txt": No such file or directory

simulation terminated by an assertion at initialization
Simulation process failed. Exited with code 255.
```

which I don't understand at all, given that `loadResource` works correctly.

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `Modelica.Utilities.Files.loadResource` in the modifier for the `fileName` in `combiTable1Ds`. Note that `Modelica.Utilities.Files.loadResource` is a *BAD* name, the function does *NOT load* anything, it just translates from a Modelica URI to an absolute file path to the resource.

```
within TestURI2;
model loadURI2
  Integer x;
  parameter String filepath = Modelica.Utilities.Files.loadResource("modelica://TestURI2/somefile.txt");
  Modelica.Blocks.Tables.CombiTable1Ds combiTable1Ds(fileName = filepath, tableName = "bla", tableOnFile = true)  annotation(Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-60, 68}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
equation
combiTable1Ds.u = time;
x  = Modelica.Utilities.Strings.length(filepath);
end loadURI2;
```

Comment: Thanks, I realised this workaround late last night, too! I could have sworn I read somewhere (OM tracker? MSL tracker?) that the Combi*Tables internally use `loadResource` for resolving the path, which is why I expected this to work. I can't find the relevant passage again, unfortunately.

Comment: A related issue is [this](https://trac.openmodelica.org/OpenModelica/ticket/4583) - initially I just had the filename in the `fileName` argument. As the file is in the same place as the Modelica file, I expected this to resolve correctly. However, the OMEdit *working directory*, which seems to be the relevant root for resolution, is somehere in `/tmp/`, not where the files are, so this did not find the file. That's when I started to investigate the URI approach. Although that is a bit ugly since needs me to define a *package* -- I don't think it works with a plain model, at least it works now.

Comment: The executable will read the file from the current directory which in case of OMEdit is somewhere in %TMP%. If you would use command line via omc script.mos and run the command where the file is, it would work. But is best to just make a proper Modelica library and use the URIs.